# Updating a custom field set for case entity Civi API

Tags: api, civicase

I have defined a custom field for a particular case type ("adhesion") it's a yes or no field that I need to update when I finish the processing. So I use the Case API to update it passing the id and the new value for the custom field. But this doesn't update the value I get this as a return in the API explorer. I was able to update custom fields in others entities and update case predifined fields using the API.

Is there any explantion for this problem? Any hint on how i can achieve this update action.

Down below is a screenshot from the API explorer [image]

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug to me. Looking at the code you can see in [`civicrm_api3_case_create`](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/api/v3/Case.php#L62-L62) that if the ID is already set it calls `civicrm_api3_case_update`.

`civicrm_api3_case_update` has no call to the `CRM_Case_BAO_Case::create` method, which is the only mention I see of custom parameter creation in the BAO.

In fact api/v3/Case.php contains only one mention of the word "custom". It's surprising that something like this could have been left out and maybe I'm missing something, but when I tried creating a custom field for a Case locally and setting some custom values nothing was created.

I'd suggest mentioning this in [Mattermost](https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/user-support) or just going ahead and creating a bug report for it on [Jira](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/)

Edit:

[This issue](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18082) is about custom data being ignored by the case API but is still open.

Comment: I am having the same issue.  I ended up just doing a query directly in the DB through the Drupal abstraction layer.  Not the best things but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question, but you might contemplate using [CiviRules](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules) to update the case custom field?

Comment: Thank you @ErikH well for now and because i'm in rush what i used to update was sql query to update the custom field table entries. And it's working but i will have a look on that too.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the Case API doesn't support custom fields... However, good news! From 4.7.25 the Case API DOES supports custom fields!
https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18082